# iBooot и несобственные посты

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, бот

При затирании поста [iBooot](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/322268/ibooot) пишет:

> Пожалуйста, не создавайте лишнюю работу другим участникам, вандализируя собственные посты. При размещении сообщения на сайте «Stack Overflow на русском» вы даёте SO, в соответствии с лицензией [CC BY-SA 3.0](//ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported#%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4), неотзываемое право на распространение своего контента. В соответствии с политикой SO любые вандальные действия будут отменены. Если вы желаете узнать больше про удаление постов, пожалуйста, прочитайте [Как работает удаление?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293).

Однако [в ревизиях](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/988252/revisions) видно, что пост был не собственный.

Возможно, сообщение надо подправить? Или бота?

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я помню видел в чате рекомендации "не затирайте сообщения" (мотивировалось: для обучения алгоритмов ботов), правильно: ставить тревогу.

Если следовать этой рекомендации, то участник из благих побуждений (убрать побыстрее текст вопроса) поступил неправильно.

Надо было поставить тревогу и спокойно ждать, когда проблема будет решена.

Однако эта рекомендация подходит только к какому-то абстрактному миру, в котором все участники знают все правила и поступают всегда правильно. Уверен: проблемы подобного рода будут так или иначе возникать.

Мне кажется правильным переписать бота. Однозначно ситуация, когда сам автор вандализирует собственный пост встречается чаще, чем приведённая в вопросе. И вероятно, можно получить более точные срабатывания если различать сам автор / не сам автор.